# Broken jQuery Call Funciton

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Little random issue we just can't seem to see/fix, when we call `enquiryform()` within a load or ready script the form either works and breaks another or doesn't work and allows everything else to work perfectly.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with the snippet below?

```
function enquiryform(){
    $('#enquiry-form').validate({
        rules:{
            email: 'required email'
        },
        messages:{
            email:{
                required: 'Please enter your email address.',
                email: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
             }
        },

        errorContainer: '.errorwrapper',
        errorLabelContainer: '.errorwrapper .error',

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: You call this function in `$(document).ready(...)`; ?

Comment: This is what I'm currently using to call the function. $(document).ready(function(){ 
enquiryform(); 
});

Comment: Is this a specific jQuery plugin?

Comment: We are using 'http://jqueryvalidation.org/' jQuery validation.

Comment: So I've check the console log and this error is showing: 

TypeError: 
$(...).validate is not a function
submitHandler: function (form) {

Comment: Are you sure the validation plugin is loaded?

Comment: I'm sure it was but never mind now, I've solved the issue myself. Thank you for your input anyways.

Comment: Try to keep the answers in the answer, not the question

Answer (score 0):

We managed to find the solution out ourselves, please see the answer below:

```
function enquiryform() {
    $('#enquiry-form').validate({
        rules: {
            email: 'required email'
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email address.',
                email: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
            }
        },

        errorContainer: $('.errorwrapper'),
        errorLabelContainer: $('.errorwrapper .error'),

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: wrapping your those two error options in `$(..)` should not fix anything like the issue you were suggesting